# Get total number of occurrences of a string in json using jq

Tags: json, count, jq

I want to get count of number of occurrences of "1.2.3.46:8983_emo" in this json string using jq.

1.2.3.46:8983_emo is present under myApp & myApp_shadow. So the count will be 2

using below jq filter

```
.cluster.collections.myApp.shards.shard1.replicas[].node_name
```

I am able to get node_names but I need something like this, which is not working. I don't know how to look under 'myApp' & 'myApp_shadow'. Can you please help

```
.cluster.collections | select (.myApp.shards.shard1.replicas[].node_name=="1.2.3.46:8983_emo")
```

Here is the snippet...https://jqplay.org/s/VvdATQ6bAr

FYI..when i try just adding "| length" did not work for me. It gave wrong counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given description of the problem is very confusing.  For example, there are actually three occurrences of the JSON string "1.2.3.46:8983_emo" in the given JSON:

```
.. | strings | select(. == "1.2.3.46:8983_emo")
```

shows there are three occurrences.

If you just want to look in .myApp and .myApp_shadow, then consider:

```
.cluster.collections
| [(.myApp, .myApp_shadow) | .. | strings | select(.=="1.2.3.46:8983_emo")]
| length
```

This yields the answer you said you expect (i.e. 2).

Hopefully the above will provide sufficient guidance for you to do whatever it is you want; if not, then please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a minimal example that clarifies the issue you're having.

#### count/1

A more efficient and perhaps better approach is to use `count/1`:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);
```

This counts the number of items in the stream, s, without constructing an array. So you could for example write:

```
.cluster.collections
| "1.2.3.46:8983_emo" as $s
| count((.myApp, .myApp_shadow) | .. | strings | select(.==$s))
```

Or if you only want to check the values of the "node_name" key:

```
count(.. | select(.node_name? == "1.2.3.46:8983_emo"))
```

Comment: if you search in the json yes there is one more occurrence but I am specifically looking that value with key name as 'node_name"

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which uses [tostream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream)

```
reduce (
    tostream
  | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
  | select($p[-1]=="node_name" and $v=="1.2.3.46:8983_emo")
) as $n (0;.+1)
```